# ADT implementation in C of integer list

Tags: c, abstract-data-type

I need to do a home assignment in VC++, which uses ADT to do several operations on an integer list. For now, we're not allowed to use classes, so I need to use `struct`.

I don't quite understand how ADTs work, so I'm not sure where to start, because all tutorials on the internet use classes, which I don't want to.

So are there any tutorials on the net that: 1. explain the concept of Abstract Data Types and 2. Provide an example of implementation (preferably in C++ and not using `class`, but `struct` instead).

Comment: You can probably replace the word `class` with `struct` in any of the examples you found and have it "just work".

Comment: `struct` and `class` both designate class types. If you think that they're different, you either misunderstand, or you misrepresent your requirements.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Probably the request for not using classes means, that there should be no member functions. So I guess the `struct` should be used C like.

Comment: OP might want to tag his question "C" then.

Comment: AFAIK, classes can have methods, structs cannot. I don't think it's a matter of C/C++, but yet, since there is no OOP involved, I will re-tag this as C.

Comment: @EduardLuca: in C++, both struct and class CAN have methods. They're totally the same even up to the memory layout, only differ in default visibility (public for struct, private for class).

Comment: @LeleDumbo I see, didn't know that. Well then it's clearly a matter of C and not C++, as I want procedural programming, rather than object oriented.

Comment: Tutorial link: http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~selfpace/studyguide/9C.sg/Output/ADTs.in.C.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a try for an answer that is more what is my understanding.

1. What is an abstract datatype?
   Always my first shot: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type

My "practical" understanding of this is: There is some idea of an object that is defined by the object, its variables (or data) and the operations that are defined on this object.
For your case the object is a list of integers. The operations are something like `insert a new integer`, `remove an integer`, `get the number of integers stored in the list` and so on. When implementing this datatype you have to write this operations as functions. To provide this functions you will have to make up some structure to save the data to operate on.

1. Provide an example of implementation.

Well I won't do your homework so I will do some pseudocode:

```
struct ListElement {
   int value;
   type NextElement; //i leave the type to you
};

void insertBehind(ListElement &element, int newValue)//this is one way to do this
{
  ListElement newElement(newValue); //create the new element (use new instead, don't want to "spoiler" the type to you)
  newElement.nextElement = element.nextElement; //set the next element of this new one
  element.NextElement = newElement; //set the new element
}

...
```

Comment: That's pretty much the implementation I was going to write, but then I thought of something: since it's an **abstract** data type, shouldn't it work with any type of variables? On the `insertBehind` function the 2nd param is an int, shouldn't it be a generic type? I do realize that at some point I will have to tell the program what the 'abstract' type is (the int), but are you sure this implementation is valid ADT? Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: @EduardLuca: Well that would be the usecase for a template. But this is C++ and far from what is expected in the task. But you are right. The abstract idea does not restrict the type that is saved inside the list. You could have a look at the `std::list` to see one example of the template usage in C++, but be warned this is not a beginners reading.

Comment: I see. I will have to use templates eventually, but not now. I've read something about being able to achieve the `abstract` pattern by defining the variables as `void*`, but really not sure about how to use that, so I'll stick to your implementation. Thank you once again.

Comment: @EduardLuca: It is possible to use `void*` but this is really bad, because you loose type safeness. Usually you only want to store variables of one type (e.g. `int`, `float`, `myOwnStruct`, ...) in the list and this type is known during compilation time. For this scenario the template versions are fully sufficient. The `void*` method would allow to insert variables of different types and further you would not know what type an element of the list has (unless there is some method provided that will tell you). To me the `void*` solution looks like it is from the C world.